# Not able to get any Events in Event channel in Skype UCWA Application

Tags: java, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I am able to create Application using a Skype UCWA APIs in a Java client.I am creating onlineMeetings and store the onlinemeeting id and the join urls in  db. What I need to do when someone using this `joinUrl` joins a particular meeting I need to get whether they joined the meeting or left the meeting etc.

What I read from here (https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/ProgrammingConcepts-Events) . I should be able to do that by subscribing to the eventchannel on my application. But When I send a GET request like this

```
{/applications/1234/events?ack=1&amp;medium=300&amp;low=600&amp;timeout=900}
```

(This is an example)

What I get as a Responce is something like this

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"applications/1324/events?ack=1"},"next":{"href":"applications/1234/events?ack=2"}},"sender":[]}
```

I guess this is a timeout responce.

But before this responce gets and after I sent the request I join an online meeting which was created using the above mentioned skype application and type message in that meeting. But I don't get any such events like that. Instead I get this response and I suspect this is more like a Timeout response.

Can anyone of you point out what's the mistake I made here.

Updated on 24th of March(2017)

Requirement -
To check an invitee is in the lobby
Things done so far
1) Join the user who has created the online meeting using onlineMeetingUri and operationID(which is client generated)
2) Get this event in the event channel of the application which is used to join the user who created the meeting in the first place.

Things to do
3) Need to identify a user who has joined the onlinemeeting via a joiningUrl who also in the lobby. Since the onlinemeeting is created with the Access.SameEnterprise an outsider from the organization is directly placed in the lobby.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That event response above indeed does indicate that no events occurred during the timeout period (900 seconds).  Are you issuing a periodic request to reportMyActivity?  Are you you joining the online meeting from the UCWA application?  Are you continuing to follow the next href in event respones?

Comment: @ShelbyZ 1 )"Are you issuing a periodic request to reportMyActivity?" No I m not  issuing a such a request  2)  "Are you you joining the online meeting from the UCWA application?"  No I am joining the online meeting through joinURL(SkypeForBusiness client) which comes with the Post Request when an onlineMeeting is created. 3) Since I got a timeout responce I did not continue to follow next href event responces

Comment: Not calling reportMyActivity periodically will leave you application in a state where the server can/will terminate the application after some period of time.  If you are not joining the meeting from the UCWA application you would not have visibility from UCWA into who joins/leaves the meeting.  Joining via the URL launches a separate instance of a UCWA application managed via LWA.  Following event responses is how you will find out about new events in the application that have occurred since the previous request.

Comment: @ShelbyZ Thanks for the explanations. When a user joins via URL how can I get hold to this new instance of UCWA application managed via LWA. I believe i should follow event responses and call reportMyActivity from there.

Comment: Your next steps should be to call [reportMyActivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/reportmyactivity_ref) on a periodic basis, and hookup following next event responses.  You should plan to monitor people joining/leaving the meeting from the original UCWA application as the one created via launching that meeting link will not easily expose the data you are looking for.  You can use [joinOnlineMeeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/joinonlinemeeting_ref) and pass in the onlineMeetingUri to join the meeting you created with the original application.

Comment: @ShelbyZ As you mentioned I have made a call to reportMyActivity after I made a POST request to create application. Then I get the 204 status code which is correct I guess. Then I tried to made a call to [joinOnlineMeeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/joinonlinemeeting_ref). This is without adding the any onlineMeetingUri parameter to request. In that case responce says {"name":"The OperationContext field is required.","reason":"MissingOrInvalid"} I did not finy any details about these parameters in that documentation Do you have an idea about these parameters?

Comment: I believe you would need to provide the operationId and onlineMeetingUri parameters at the very least to that request.  The documentation lists no parameters as required, but it is incorrect.

Comment: @ShelbyZ I was involved in some other work recently so I was not able to look in to this. Now I was able to join into the onlinemeeting using onlineMeetingUri  and operationId(client generated). My goal is to check whether a person who I have sent a joiningURL for a particular meeting is in the lobby or not.I will update the question with my exact requirement.

Comment: You will need to keep checking the event channel and look for [participant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/participant_ref) whose state is added.  That object may/may not also expose the property, inLobby which would be what you are looking for.  They have unique identifiers that should include their SIP address and since you are using same enterprise the outsiders would all be in the lobby.  A simple call to admit (probably with an operationId) would place them in the meeting/conversation.

Comment: @ShelbyZ Thank you for your help I was able to get the participants who are in different meeting from the same event channel. What I did was to join a particular user who is in the same organization to all the meeting that i need to watch and listening to the events in event channel. Now I have another requirement on providing this solution for the Skype For Business Online as well. Earlier it was for Skype for Business on Premises only. But right now when I make a POST request to create an application , the response does not contain a "joinOnlineMeeting" uri.Do you have an idea why is that ?

Comment: @ShelbyZ When I am getting the accessTokens for resource I set the scope to "openID" . I noticed when I retrieved the response when getting the accessToken for application in SFB online the scope is set as "Meetings.ReadWrite". I believe what I needed there is "Conversations.Initiate". But not sure how to get that though.

Comment: You would need to change your Azure AD application registration to allow the features you are looking for.  I would suggest looking at [Developing Web SDK applications for Skype for Business Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline) and pay attention to the section about delegated permissions.

Comment: @ShelbyZ Yes. I have to change the scope/permissions to get joinOnlineMeeting uri as the documentation says. I have not had a try at it yet. Thanks for the information. Another issue which I face right now is I don't get the "eject" resource with Participant either localParticipant as mentioned here "https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-eject" And this is with the Skype On Premises Server. Also other related resource such as admit,contact,contactPhoto etc are also not shown with the responce in the event channel for participants. Do you have an idea what have gone wrong here